# Datepart week function wont work Please need assistance

Tags: sql, select, datepart

The table I am trying to use is

```
create type Rehearsal_ty as object
(RehID char(4),
RLocation add_ty,
Attendance varchar2 (100),
RDate date)

create table Rehearsal_tbl of Rehearsal_ty
```

The select statement I am trying to use can't get it to work

```
SELECT rehid, DATEPART(wk,rdate)
from Rehearsal_tbl

SELECT DATEPART (ww,rdate())
FROM Rehearsal_tbl;
```

please help 
really stuck

Comment: What database are you using?  For MS SQL Server the following code works: `select DATEPART(WW,GETUTCDATE())`.  As you're looking at a table in a column I wouldn't expect you to need the brackets - but that may be different in your case depending on DB.  `SELECT DATEPART(WW,rdate) FROM Rehearsal_tbl;`.  Also, when you say it's not working, are you getting a syntax error, or is the result different to what you were expecting?

Comment: I have tried both but just keep getting errors the error I recieved is:            ORA-00904: "DATEPART": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 753 Column: 7

Answer (score 0):

**(UPDATED)**
Looks like the Oracle documentation was incorrect - here's a version which works.  You can test it out here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/77080/7

```
select RehID, to_char(rdate, 'IW') as IsoWeekChar
from Rehearsal_tbl;
```

.

```
select RehID, to_char(rdate, 'WW') as IsoWeekChar
from Rehearsal_tbl;
```

.

```
select RehID, to_number(to_char(rdate, 'IW')) as IsoWeekNumeric
from Rehearsal_tbl;
```

.

```
select RehID, to_number(to_char(rdate, 'WW')) as OraWeekNumeric
from Rehearsal_tbl;
```

Comment: I have tried both select statements but no joy getting an error message ORA-00904: "DATEPART": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 230 Column: 14